# python find file and change directory to file path

Tags: python, os.walk, chdir

I'm wanting to use os.walk to search the cwd and subdirectories to locate a specific file and when found immediately break and change to that dir. I've seen many examples where it breaks after locating the file, but I can't figure out how to retrieve the path location so I can change dir.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this?

```
f = 'filename'
for path, dirs, files in os.walk('.'):
    if f in files:
        os.chdir(path)
        break
```

Comment: That was it. Simple pure concise.

Answer (score 0):

```
import os

required_file = "somefile.txt"
cwd = '.'

def get_dir_name(cwd, required_file):
  for dirName, subdirList, fileList in os.walk(cwd):
    for fname in fileList:
        if fname == required_file:
            change_to_dir = os.path.abspath(dirName)
            return change_to_dir

change_to_dir = get_dir_name(cwd, required_file)
os.chdir(change_to_dir)
```